# Opportunity Line Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

The below trigger for opportunity lines works perfectly when adding lines individually, however when adding multiple lines where there are cross sell and upsell matches the retain all on thirdset keeps product_family__c from the one value and updates all lines to upsell even if one should be cross-sell

I need to make this trigger asses and update one opp line at a time by i have been unsuccessful and am unsure how to proceed

How would i go about make it so the opplines are assessed and updated one at a time?

```
trigger OppLineLogicTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (before insert , Before Update) {
    //Declare Lists and Sets

    Set<Id> Accountids = new Set<Id>();
    Set<id> Oppsid = new Set<Id>();
    Set<String> thirdSet = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> LineItemSet = new Set<String>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLstToUpdate=new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem OpplineItemsID : Trigger.new)
    {
        Accountids.add(OpplineItemsID.account__C);
        oppsid.add(OpplineItemsID.id);
    }

    system.debug('id ' + accountids);

    //Create Lists to hold Product Family values from assets and opportunitylineitems

    List<OpportunityLineItem> ProductFamiliesOpps = [Select Product_Family__c from OpportunityLineItem where id in :oppsid Limit 1];

    list<Asset> ProductFamiliesAssests = [Select Asset_family__C from Asset where accountid in :Accountids];

    system.debug('Assets ' + ProductFamiliesAssests);
    system.debug('Assets ' + ProductFamiliesOpps);


    //loop through assets in list to store unique values in set
    for (Asset Asst : ProductFamiliesAssests) 
    {
        if(asst.Asset_Family__c != Null)
        {
            thirdSet.add(Asst.Asset_family__C );
        }
    }

    //Loop through opportunitylineitems in list to store unique values in set

    for (OpportunityLineItem Oppline : ProductFamiliesopps)
    {
        if(oppline.Product_Family__c != Null)
        {
            LineItemSet.add(Oppline.Product_Family__c );
        }
    }

    //Retain any matches in both sets - ie if list one contains acloud and dimensions and list two contains acloud then acloud is retained

    thirdSet.retainAll(LineItemSet);

    system.debug('thirdset ' + thirdSet);

    //Loop through opplineitems in trigger new and update type

    for(Opportunitylineitem Opplist1 : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(Opplist1.id != null && opplist1.Handover_Id__c == Null && ProductFamiliesOpps.size() >= 1 ){

            if(Opplist1.BecameCustomerDate__c != Null && Opplist1.oppclosedate__C < Opplist1.BecameCustomerDate__c + 180 && Opplist1.From_Acquisitionoppline__c != True )
            {
                Opplist1.type__C = 'New Business';
            }
            else if(Opplist1.BecameCustomerDate__c == Null)
            {
                Opplist1.type__C = 'New Business';
            }
            else if (!thirdSet.isEmpty())
            {
                Opplist1.type__C = 'Up-selling';
            }
            else if (thirdSet.isEmpty())
            {
                Opplist1.type__C = 'Cross-Selling';
            }

            oppLstToUpdate.add(opplist1);
            system.debug('Opp' + oppLstToUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the retain method and change the if / not empty statements to contains

```
  Else if (!thirdset.contains(opplist1.Product_Family__c)){

             Opplist1.type__C = 'Cross-Selling';

            }

        Else if (thirdset.contains(opplist1.Product_Family__c)){

         Opplist1.type__C = 'Up-Selling';
```